# Como descargar Un archivo pdf en MVC 5 directamente

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, navegador-web

Deseo que al realizar ciertas operaciones el archivo generado en pdf se descargue directamente y no se visualice en el navegador (chrome)

```
    byte[] fileBytes =  System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"\\svr\dllo\Pendientes\" + nombrePDF);
   return File(fileBytes, "application/pdf");
```

En Explorer sí lo descarga directamente

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esto lo armé hace unos años pero te puede servir.

```
        byte[] fileBytes =  System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"\\svr\dllo\Pendientes\" + nombrePDF);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(fileBytes, 0, 0, true, true);
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename= NombreArchivo");
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Clear();
        Response.OutputStream.Write(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, ms.GetBuffer().Length);
        Response.OutputStream.Flush();
        Response.End();
        return new FileStreamResult(Response.OutputStream, "application/pdf");
```

El secreto está en esta línea:
`Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;`

El explorador debería bajarlo como un adjunto y no abrirlo directamente.

Comment: hola pablo en la linea Response.AddHeader NombreArchivo es el que yo le asigne ??? en mi caso es -->nombrePDF

Comment: Claro. Si querés podés pasar la variable. Algo asi: `"attachment;filename=" + nombrePDF`

Answer (score 2):

Para forzar la descarga debes indicar el `Content-Disposition`

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=FileName.pdf");
```

[Force Download Pdf File in C# (Asp.Net Mvc 4)](https://skullbogger.wordpress.com/2015/12/19/force-download-pdf-file-in-c-asp-net-mvc-4/)

como veras varia un poco si es un action en un controller de webapi

Answer (score 0):

Yo utilizo este código.

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

public ActionResult DamePdf(LDModel ld, string returnUrl)
{
  string contentType = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf;
  return new FilePathResult(ld.fullPathfileName, contentType)
  //{ 
  //    FileDownloadName = ld.FileName,
  //};
}
```

La acción en lugar de de devolver una vista, devolverá un archivo.
si se descomenta las 3 ultimas lineas, al llegar el archivo se guardará directamente en la carpeta de descargas del explorador con el nombre que le pongamos. Si es así, el nombre debe terminar en .pdf

Teniendo nombre, depende del explorador el comportamiento puede ser diferente. Unos lo guardan sin preguntar, otros lo muestran sin preguntar y otros preguntan en cualquier caso. Cuando no lleva nombre, algunos exploradores, los buenos, lo abren directamente.

Si cambias la linea donde se define contentType  por:

```
string contentType = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet;
```

Concretamente Crhome lo guarda directamente sin preguntar nada.

Comment: Ese vinculo es muy interesante muchas gracias.